# How to set a colour gradient for all chapter headings?

Tags: sectioning, color, gradient

How can I set the text colour of all chapters to the following gradient?

```
linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(254,122,58,1) 0%, rgba(218,60,152,1) 100%)
```

At first glance, the obvious choice would be the [`gradient-text` package](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/gradient-text/gradient-text.pdf), but it explicitly says:

> `{⟨text⟩}` is the text you desire to have gradient color. Be aware that this command most
> likely wouldn’t output content as expected if this parameter is filled with tokens that
> cannot expand into pure text.

That makes it impossible to use necessary commands like `\thechapter` (which I tried unsuccessfully).

ChatGPT recommended me the following code, though it won't print the actual chapter heading, but only the text `\protect\rule` (the gradient is fine, though).

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{gradient-text}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] (gradient) {
                \gradientRGB{\rule{8cm}{2cm}}{254,122,58}{218,60,152}
            };
            \node[anchor=west, text=white] at (gradient.west) {\thechapter};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
}{20pt}{\Huge}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter One}

blablabla

\end{document}
```

Are there any alternatives? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome. Please provide a complete minimal example rather than code fragments. You need to provide something people can copy-paste-compile to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear from your question exactly what you want, but perhaps something like this?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{gradient-text}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newcommand{\mygradient}[1]{\gradientRGB{#1}{254,122,58}{218,60,152}}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
    {\ExpandArgs{x}\mygradient{\chaptertitlename\space\thechapter}}
    {20pt}
    {\Huge\ExpandArgs{x}\mygradient}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Some title}

\end{document}
```

[image]

There are some limitations to what you can put in the argument of `\chapter`, but simple things like `\the<counter>` should expand into text.

Comment: If `\ExpandArgs` should use `e`-type expansion instead, I am happy to be corrected

Comment: Yes, that's precisely what I'm trying to achieve – thank you very much! :)